# I can't figure out my error (codelab)

Tags: c++

So I have to finish these programming exercises and I'm getting an error message but I don't know why. Here is the problem.

Write the implementation (.cpp file) of the Averager class  of the previous exercise. The full specification of the class  is:

An data member named  sum  of type  integer .

An data member named  count of type  integer .

A constructor  with no parameters . The constructor  initializes  the data members sum  and the data member count to 0.

A function named  getSum that accepts no parameters  and returns an integer . getSum returns the value  of sum .

A function named  add that accepts an integer  parameter  and returns no value . add increases  the value  of sum  by the value  of the parameter , and increments  the value  of count by one.

A function named  getCount that accepts no parameters  and returns an integer . getCount returns the value  of the count data member, that is, the number of values  added to sum .

A function named  getAverage that accepts no parameters  and returns a double . getAverage returns the average of the values  added to sum . The value  returned should be a value  of type  double  (and therefore you must cast the data members to double  prior to performing the division).

And here is my code

```
Averager::Averager()
{
    sum= 0;
    count= 0;
}

int Averager::getSum()
{ return sum;}

void Averager::add(int num)
{ 
    sum += num;
    count++;
}

int Averager::getCount()
{ return count;}

double Averager::getAverage()
{
    static_cast <double> (count);
    static_cast <double> (sum);
    return sum / count;
}
```

And now here is the error message I keep getting 
 ⇒     *** Error *** Check your getAverage function

Is it my code or the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your cast. Try:

```
double Averager::getAverage()
{
    return (double)sum / count;
}
```